# Understanding <__libc_init_array> in RISCV assembly

Tags: assembly, startup, elf, riscv

My goal is to run a compiled `C` code in my `RISCV` simlator. I have compiled a C code with RISCV32I (32bit) compiler and it output my code in ELF format (then i have selected `.text` section and used it in my `RISC-V` simulator). Perfect. Then, i tried to run that compiled code in my simulator, but i found that in in `<__libc_init_array>` function there is "some" code that will always jump to the adress 0 of my program, which i dont want, obviously.

Disassembly of my output file:

```
 000102ec <__libc_init_array>:
   102ec:   ff010113            addi    sp,sp,-16
   102f0:   00812423            sw  s0,8(sp)
   102f4:   01212023            sw  s2,0(sp)
   102f8:   00001417            auipc   s0,0x1
   102fc:   3c840413            addi    s0,s0,968 # 116c0 <__init_array_start>
   10300:   00001917            auipc   s2,0x1
   10304:   3c090913            addi    s2,s2,960 # 116c0 <__init_array_start>
   10308:   40890933            sub s2,s2,s0
   1030c:   00112623            sw  ra,12(sp)
   10310:   00912223            sw  s1,4(sp)
   10314:   40295913            srai    s2,s2,0x2
   10318:   00090e63            beqz    s2,10334 <__libc_init_array+0x48>
   1031c:   00000493            li  s1,0
   10320:   00042783            lw  a5,0(s0)
   10324:   00148493            addi    s1,s1,1
   10328:   00440413            addi    s0,s0,4
   1032c:   000780e7            jalr    a5
   10330:   fe9918e3            bne s2,s1,10320 <__libc_init_array+0x34>
   10334:   00001417            auipc   s0,0x1
   10338:   38c40413            addi    s0,s0,908 # 116c0 <__init_array_start>
   1033c:   00001917            auipc   s2,0x1
   10340:   38c90913            addi    s2,s2,908 # 116c8 <__init_array_end>
   10344:   40890933            sub s2,s2,s0
   10348:   40295913            srai    s2,s2,0x2
   1034c:   dbdff0ef            jal ra,10108 <_fini>
   10350:   00090e63            beqz    s2,1036c <__libc_init_array+0x80>
   10354:   00000493            li  s1,0
   10358:   00042783            lw  a5,0(s0)
   1035c:   00148493            addi    s1,s1,1
   10360:   00440413            addi    s0,s0,4
   10364:   000780e7            jalr    a5
   10368:   fe9918e3            bne s2,s1,10358 <__libc_init_array+0x6c>
   1036c:   00c12083            lw  ra,12(sp)
   10370:   00812403            lw  s0,8(sp)
   10374:   00412483            lw  s1,4(sp)
   10378:   00012903            lw  s2,0(sp)
   1037c:   01010113            addi    sp,sp,16
   10380:   00008067            ret
```

On the line `10350` we can find an comparison that if true, will jump over a few lines. But for some reason it is not true, so we must continue. And here it becomes interesting. The next instruction loads a `0` into register `s1`, fine, but the next one tries to load some value into reg `a5` from address `0(s0)`. But the output of the read will be `0`, because in the memory there is nothing. I could not find any reference to this specific address form start of this code (from `_start`). In fact, there is no attempt to write or read to that address at all apart from this function.

```
   10350:   00090e63            beqz    s2,1036c <__libc_init_array+0x80>
   10354:   00000493            li  s1,0
   10358:   00042783            lw  a5,0(s0)
   1035c:   00148493            addi    s1,s1,1
   10360:   00440413            addi    s0,s0,4
   10364:   000780e7            jalr    a5
```

Am i missing something? This is the last step before the program jumps to the main section so i do not want to go back to address `0`.

Thanks for any help

**EDIT**

There is a dump of `.init_array` and `.data`, but I don't see how they can effect the value on the problematic address (there is even compressed instruction and some unknown FLD, both of these are unsupported by my simulator).

```
Disassembly of section .init_array:

000116c0 <__init_array_start>:
   116c0:   00ac                    addi    a1,sp,72
   116c2:   0001                    nop

000116c4 <__frame_dummy_init_array_entry>:
   116c4:   01a8                    addi    a0,sp,200
   116c6:   0001                    nop

Disassembly of section .fini_array:

000116c8 <__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry>:
   116c8:   0160                    addi    s0,sp,140
   116ca:   0001                    nop

Disassembly of section .data:

000116d0 <__DATA_BEGIN__>:
   116d0:   0000                    unimp
   116d2:   0000                    unimp
   116d4:   19bc                    addi    a5,sp,248
   116d6:   0001                    nop
   116d8:   1a24                    addi    s1,sp,312
   116da:   0001                    nop
   116dc:   1a8c                    addi    a1,sp,368
   116de:   0001                    nop
    ...
   11778:   0001                    nop
   1177a:   0000                    unimp
   1177c:   0000                    unimp
   1177e:   0000                    unimp
   11780:   330e                    fld ft6,224(sp)
   11782:   abcd                    j   11d74 <__BSS_END__+0x230>
   11784:   1234                    addi    a3,sp,296
   11786:   e66d                    bnez    a2,11870 <__DATA_BEGIN__+0x1a0>
   11788:   deec                    sw  a1,124(a3)
   1178a:   0005                    c.nop   1
   1178c:   0000000b            0xb
    ...
```

Comment: `10338` sets up `s0` to point to `__init_array_start`. `s2` is set up to be the size of that array. If the size is not zero, there should most certainly be something in the array which is not `NULL` or else you have some problem. Note it's data so you won't see any code writing to it.

Comment: @Jester That makes sense, Thank you. But this runs on startup of my program, before the main setction, so how am i supposed to modify the data on that adress? The code is auto-generated form the compiler so i do not know why is not 0.

Comment: `__init_array_start` array holds addresses of global constructors. For some reason linker resolves one of these addresses to `NULL` but it's not possible to say why without full reprocase.

Comment: @yugr Thanks. My program starts on _start section, then it jumps into some functions like _memset and so on. Please note that i only run my program from _start, with clear memory. It never writes anything to this adress. So i am not sure what and why is it trying to do.

Comment: "with clear memory" - do you mean that all memory is set to zero at start? You'll need to initialize `.data` segment from ELF file.

Comment: @yugr Thanks, please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: They are not instructions, it's pointless to try and disassemble them. Anyway, we can see your array has one element and it's not `NULL`. It's `000100ac`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code which you pointed out scans contents of `.init_array` section from `__init_array_start` to `__init_array_end`. This section contains addresses of global constructors which need to be run before executing `main` (BTW as you mentioned it does not make sense to disassemble this section as it contains data, not code, so you need to use `objdump -s` instead of `objdump -d`). You can see that addresses are initialized here:

```
10338:   38c40413            addi    s0,s0,908 # 116c0 <__init_array_start>
...
10340:   38c90913            addi    s2,s2,908 # 116c8 <__init_array_end>
```

and then used to compute size of section (in 4-byte words):

```
10344:   40890933            sub s2,s2,s0
10348:   40295913            srai    s2,s2,0x2
```

Then startup code proceeds with looping over pointers in `.init_array` and executing them:

```
10350:   00090e63            beqz    s2,1036c <__libc_init_array+0x80>  ; Skip if .init_array is empty
10354:   00000493            li  s1,0         ; Initialize loop counter
10358:   00042783            lw  a5,0(s0)     ; Load address of global ctor
1035c:   00148493            addi    s1,s1,1  ; Increment loop counter
10360:   00440413            addi    s0,s0,4  ; Compute address which holds address of next global pointer
10364:   000780e7            jalr    a5       ; Execute global ctor
10368:   fe9918e3            bne s2,s1,10358 <__libc_init_array+0x6c>  ; Loop if within .init_array
```

According to data in your question there are no NULL entries in your `.init_array` section so my only guess is that for some reason data segment (`.data`, `.rodata`, `.init_array`, etc.) is not loaded properly from ELF file at start of simulation (you also mention that you provide only `.text` section to simulator).